# Sending and receiving files in java web applications

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, httpclient

Hi I am working on web application where I **need to transfer any type**
of **file from on web app to another**.

I **able to transfer data as string format** but I am facing problem when
I need to transfer files. First I show code used to transfer data as
parameter from sender to receiver.

**Sender Side**:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();  
HttpMethod method = new PostMethod("http://192.168.1.108:8081/Receiver-Server/registerAction");  
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
NameValuePair nvp1= new NameValuePair("name", "Aniket");
NameValuePair nvp2= new NameValuePair("Age", "26");

method.setQueryString(new NameValuePair[]{nvp1,nvp2});  
int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
System.out.println(statusCode);
```

Now the **receiver side**,

```
String userName = request.getParameter("name");
String age = request.getParameter("Age");
```

Above I am successfully getting data.  So now I need to transfer any
type of file, but getting problem.

So can anyone help me to solve this issue, any hint or tutorial is
better to be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend looking at the PostMethod.setRequestEntity method, as well as the FileRequestEntity class, assuming you're using Apache's HttpClient library.

Comment: Better to use MultipartEntityBuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transferring the file requires multipart HTTP request. HTTPClient recently introduced `MultipartEntityBuilder` to make it easy to develop. Complete project can be downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/literakl/SandBox/tree/master/web-module/src/main/java/cz/literak/sandbox/so/http/upload)

`HttpClient` code that uploads a file

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
try {
    FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);
    HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addPart("bin", bin).build();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    CloseableHttpResponse postResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    try {
        writer.println(postResponse.getStatusLine());
        HttpEntity postResponseEntity = postResponse.getEntity();
        if (postResponseEntity != null) {
            writer.println(EntityUtils.toString(postResponseEntity));
        }
    } finally {
        postResponse.close();
    }
} finally {
    httpClient.close();
}
```

A Servlet that use `FileUpload` to receive the file

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
factory.setRepository(repository);

ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
for (FileItem item : items) {
    if (!item.isFormField()) {
        writer.println("fieldName = " + item.getFieldName());
        writer.println("fileName = " + item.getName());
        writer.println("contentType = " + item.getContentType());
        writer.println("size [bytes] = " + item.getSize());
        File uploadedFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".txt");
        item.write(uploadedFile);
        writer.println("stored as  " + uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

I think that the code is so easy that it does not need explanation but feel free to ask.

One important note: never ever use supplied file name as filename of created file. This is a security risk.

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you please tell how can I get/read this file at server/receiver side....

Comment: Later. Http commons upload library.

Comment: Can you please send some code or any tutorial page for reading response, because I tried with your example also with addText instead of sending file but i am getting null value...

Comment: Does it work for you? You can checkout complete GitHub project and run it.

Comment: Thanks Friend for nice explanation & time you have given me...its working for me...